# Android - How to display a disclaimer before asking for permissions

Tags: android, flutter

According with the Google policies for location, a disclaimer must be displayed before asking for permissions, but, with the Permissions handler package, the permissions are asked before the disclaimer dialog. How may I sort this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `AlertDialog` and trigger permission when the user clicks on Grant Button.

You can trigger this dialog in `initstate`

Code in Action

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    title: const Text("Alert"),
    content: const Text("I need Permission......"),
    actions: [
      TextButton(
        child: const Text("Grant Permission"),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          // Reguest permission here
        }
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: I did it but, if the user does click outside the alert dialog, it dismiss and the permissions are never asked for.
UPDATE: *barrierDismissible: false,* did the trick.